# How express the max of a sequence of integers divisible by n

Tags: notation, integers

`u` represents the largest integer in a sequence of integers ranging from 1 to 100 that are also divisible by 7.

Something like:

`u = MAX([1..n] where n < 100 and n mod 7 = 0)`

What is an acceptable way I could express this using mathematical notation?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: You've been here long enough to know about MathJax. Please use it.

Comment: Sorry, I visited a while ago, thought I knew about maths, then realised I didn't know anything, so hadn't been back. I was actually a bit apprehensive about asking a question because I didn't want to feel stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is that it appears you are maximizing [$1$ .. $n$], (whatever that means), rather than $n$.

I would phrase it as
$$\max(\{n \in \{1,...,100\} \mid n\;\text{is divisible by $7$}\})$$
or, more formally,
$$\max(
\{
n \in \mathbb{Z}\mid 
1 \le n \le 100
\;\,\text{and}\;
n \equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;7)
\}
$$

Comment: Or $98$ for short . . .

Comment: I would like to express it as a pluggable formula where the range end is pluggable as well as the divisor. Is that possible?

Comment: I know very little but you do seem to understand that I want the max of a list of numbers that is also divisible by a given number.

Comment: To summarise, does it means n is in the set containing integers 1 to 100 that are also divisible by 7? Then getting the max of that set?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$.